# Billing period anchor in create checkout session?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to add the timestamp for when to start the next billing in checkout session. Is this possible?

Here is my current code for creating the subscription (subscription product is already created in the console)

However, I want to make this start after some period of time.

```
try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      mode: "subscription",
      customer: customerID,
      line_items: [
        {
          price: price_blahblahblah,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      success_url: YOUR_DOMAIN+"/profile",
      cancel_url: YOUR_DOMAIN+"/subscribe",
    });
    res.json({success: true, url: session.url});
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({success: false, message: e.message});
  }
```

Comment: That's not supported in Checkout today.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out. I had to use a combination of:

subscription_data = {
        trial_period_days: 2,
} 
and 
 subscription_data = {
        trial_end: billingAnchor,
 };
because trial_end only supports max of 48hrs